# Challenge with Laravel Checkbox to Publish or Not Publish Post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a question about Laravel. I am creating a blog that allows the user to upload a new post to the page. Below is the picture about how the form looks like when the user clicks the button `Create New Post` on the page.

In the form, there is a checkbox called `Publish` which allows the user to choose if they want to publish the post or not.

1. If the user checks "Publish", the post will be displayed on the page with the word `published` on the column "Published".
2. If the user checks "No Publish", when they click the button "Save", the post won't be displayed on the page.

Does anyone know how to do it? I am new to Laravel so I have no idea how to do it. I did a search on gg and people talking about something called Controller. Do I need it to do the Publish and No Publish feature?

Picture of page:

The main page where the post will be displayed (in the "Published" field should have the word "Published" in it)

[image: post panel]

The form when user clicks on the button `Create New Post`

[image: modal form new post]

Post Schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('author');
        $table->boolean('published')->default(0);
        //create the relationship between a task and the user that created it
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Post Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body', 'author', 'published'
    ];

    public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->user_id = Auth::id();
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            $model->user_id = Auth::id();
        });
    }
}
```

`app/Http/Livewire/Posts.php`

```php
class Posts extends Component
{
    public $posts, $title, $body, $post_id, $author, $published;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $this->posts = $user->posts;
        return view('livewire.posts');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->openModal();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function openModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private function resetInputFields()
    {
        $this->title = '';
        $this->body = '';
        $this->post_id = '';
        $this->author = '';
        $this->published = '';
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'author' => 'required',
            'published' => 'required'
        ]);

        Post::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->post_id], [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'author' => $this->author,
            'published' => $this->published
        ]);

        session()->flash('message',
            $this->post_id ? 'Post Updated Successfully.' : 'Post Created Successfully.');

        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $this->post_id = $id;
        $this->title = $post->title;
        $this->body = $post->body;
        $this->author = $post->author;
        $this->published = $post->published;
        $this->openModal();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        Post::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Post Deleted Successfully.');
    }
}
```

This is the .blade code I use to create checkbox for 'Publish'

```html
<div class="mb-4">
    <label for="check" class="form-check-label">Publish:</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" id="check" value="publish" type="checkbox" name="published" wire:model="published">Publish</input>
    <input class="form-check-input" id="check" value="no-publish" type="checkbox" name="published" wire:model="published">No Publish</input>
</div>
```

Comment: What part are you having issues with? BTW element IDs need to be unique on each page, you currently have `id="check"` twice.

Comment: First of all you should use radio buttons, so you can switch between the states of the posts. second of all: you are declaring the check boxes wrong way, `name` can not be the same for different statuses. More than that, there should not be equal names in the form at all, or you should use `name="published[]"` array abbreviation to store the results of the user checks.

Comment: Like I don't know where to start, can you give me an idea where which file to look into? I search on gg and see that people talking about Controller. Do I need to have a controller to do it?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're using checkbox don't need have two for that, check-boxes are optional things...this way is logical that if the user want to publish the post select the checkbox, if not just doesn't select it.
in modal blade

```
<div class="mb-4">
    <label for="check" class="form-check-label">Publish:</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" id="check" value="publish" type="checkbox" name="published" wire:model="published">Publish</input>
</div>
```

By default, in component, $this->published = 0. But change to 1 if the user mark checkbox as selected, that way you can store this value in post model db and retrieve it. When the data is listed in blade, like your table you can do this

```
<table>
   <thead>
    // ...
   <tr>
     <th>Published</th>
     //....
   <tbody>
   @foreach(...)
     <tr>
      //.....
       <td>
           @if($posts->published) Published @endif
       </td>  
   //....
```

Hope this help you. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

you can return only published post by adding query into list method

```
$user->posts->where("published",1)->get();
```

also use global scope which will let you only deal with posts with your condition https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes